# Microsoft Access-Build a query that Correlates a tables fields

Tags: ms-access

This is pretty hard to explain so I will try to be as clear as I can in a step by step format.

1. Currently I have a query set up that looks at multiple criteria and gives me results for items that do not match the criteria based on a class/Supplier level.
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbrsX.jpg ''
2. Each query is based on what I want the results to comeback as for a specific set of Class/Supplier related outcomes. For example; Class,1,2,3,4 With Suppliers 800,801,802 should have these results and Class 5,6,7 with Suppliers 800,801,802 should have these results.
3. The query as it is set up is looking at the Class and the Supplier number. So for example, I would have to look at all of class 16 with all of the Specific Supplier numbers(1,2,3,4,5,etc)
4. I have the "Class" as one field in the Query and "Supplier" as another field in the query.
5. Right now there are about 12 different criteria that I look at, so 12 different rows and I have to input the Class and the Correlating Supplier in each row.
6. Because of this I have to create Multiple queries for the different classes, and different suppliers, so a separate query for Class 2, Supplier 802,803. a separate query for class 1, 802,803(If I want a different result) This is because I am looking for different outcomes.
7. What I would like to do is build a table with all the classes and suppliers that I want to see a specific result from,but the Class/Supplier correlation has to remain in tact. Meaning in the table with field listed as Class and Field listed as supplier, If row 1's data is "Class" 1, "Supplier" 801 then the query inputs that data from the table and so on for each row, instead of me building a query for each class and the multiple suppliers. Like the table below, which the query would look at where input in the query is Class 11, Supplier 839640118, then Class 11, Supplier 832180111 and etc.

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsWDa.jpg 'Table with Class and Suppliers"

I can elaborate more if this does not help. If there is a way for me to send screenshots, I can do that as well.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, resp. what you actually want to achieve. Can you try to elaborate in your question - if possible, with input data and expected result?

Comment: Sorry, I made the correction to the text and hopefully it is a clearer picture. It is hard to explain through text with no visual.

Comment: (don't really have time now to analyze your edit) You can upload screenshots to http://imgur.com/ and insert the images or (if you don't have enough rep) post the links. http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html is useful for sample data (paste output and format as code).

Comment: Here's a nice place to start: [spaghettidba](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)